# Mac OSX 10.6 preference panes and ARC

Tags: macos, automatic-ref-counting

Can I run a preference pane built using ARC and x86_64 (10.9 SDK) and targeted for 10.6 under 10.6 or will it only run under 10.8 or later?  I keep getting "GC compatibility mismatch errors" when I try to launch it under 10.6 and 10.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64-bit preference panes in 10.6 and 10.7 have to use garbage collection, not ARC. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146970/apple-prefpane-example-fails-to-build-with-clang-error-objecting-to-both-fobjc) for more.

Comment: Thanks Chuck. But the latest version of Xcode 5 deprecates GC.  I can't even build my code anymore unless I switch to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download an older version of Xcode (5.0.2, I think) that supports Garbage Collection in order to build the 64-bit pref-panes.

Or you could build a 32-64-bit prefpane, which the older OSes will attempt to load the 32-bit one after failing to load the 64-bit one. Note that you will need to either compile it using manual retain count, or have some bridging functions to handle retain and release.